# Stream audio from my iPhone to my mac computer via bluetooth using A2DP?

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, bluetooth, a2dp

Both OSX and the iPhone support A2DP, both as source-only. I would like to be able to transmit the audio from the iPod app (and other compatible applications) to my computer, i.e. to use my mac as "headphones".
I've searched a bit and I couldn't find anything to make that happen, so here I am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [don't](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=746197) think [its](http://bluesoleil.walrusclub.com/2009/06/27/stream-music-from-your-iphone-to-your-pc-via-bluetooth-prasys-blog/) possible (yet) to [do so using Bluetooth](http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1077043).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

I thought of a (lame) alternative: [A2DP receiver -> computer's line-in](http://www.google.com/products?q=a2dp+receiver)

It should work, though it'd be an extra piece of hardware to buy and keep charged instead of having the computer "just work"

### Solution 2 (preferred)

Eventually I fixed this problem by using an AirPort Express connected to my computer's external speakers ([they](http://www.cnet.com/products/logitech-z4/) have two inputs). Similarly I could have used a mini-jack Y-splitter to connect both sources to the input.

Now I can stream to my computer's speakers without having it on or connected at all, and it works over AirPlay/WiFi, which likely has higher quality.

Comment: Wish there was 1 device that has the Bluetooth A2DP receiver on the on end, and internally do the line conversion to a USB audio input/interface. So a USB audio card (1 input only) and a Bluetooth A2DP receiver combined in 1 device (skipping the 3.5mm line-in-out plugs).

Answer (score 1):

You can install Linux in a virtual machine (e.g. using VMWare or Parallels Workstation), then

- either assign your system's Bluetooth adapter exclusively to the VM if you don't need Bluetooth functionality in Mac OS or
- connect an additional Bluetooth Adapter to your Mac, then connect this new one to the VM (such adapters cost a few dollars on dx.com or similar)

Then inside the Linux VM use these instructions for setting up a Bluetooth A2DP sink:
https://gist.github.com/joergschiller/1673341